# setRGB cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: java, ioexception

Trying to correct a set of "out of order pixels", listed in a XML file previously parsed in Array (number of column on x assis, number of detectors failed) in TIF image using interpolation of (x-1) and (x+ number of failed detectors)/2.
In Input I have a Tif image, as single layer (PAN, MS1, MS2, MS3, MS4) and the Array. In output I want the new image corrected.
I'm having problems with setRGB in :

> new_img.setRGB = ((row + numOfDetectors) + (row - 1)/ 2);

and IOException e, in :

> } catch (IOException e) {

Sorry, I'm new in Java language. Thanks ..

```
class ArrayInterpolatorNew {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String path  = "E:/IES_Interpol/Resources/Images/ByPass_PAN_C.tif";
    String path1 = "E:/IES_Interpol/Resources/Images/ByPass_PAN_C_interpol.tif";

    BufferedImage old_img = null;   

    try { old_img = ImageIO.read(new File(path));} 
        catch (Exception e) {  e.printStackTrace(); }  

        // Developer may get all the pixels
        int width  = old_img.getWidth(null);
        int height = old_img.getHeight(null);


        BufferedImage new_img = new BufferedImage( old_img.getWidth(),
                      old_img.getHeight(), 
                      BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);

        Graphics gr = new_img.getGraphics();

        gr.drawImage(old_img, 0, 0, null);
        gr.dispose();

        try {   
            File file = new File("Resources/Images/ByPass_PAN_C_interpol.tif"); // The file to save to.
            String format = "TIF"; // Example: "PNG" or "JPG"
            BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            ImageIO.write(new_img, "TIF", new File(path1));   
        //} 
        //catch (IOException e)   { e.printStackTrace(); }  

            byte pix[] = new byte[1];
            int n = new_img.getWidth();
            int m = new_img.getHeight();
            final int firstRow = 1;
            final int numOfDetectors = 1;
            //int row = image1.getWidth();
            //int col = image1.getHeight();
            double[][] matrix = new double[n][m];
            double[][] Array = new double[firstRow][numOfDetectors];

            //swips the rows
            for (int row = 0; row < n; ++row) 
            {
                //swips the columns
                for (int col = 0; col < m; ++col) 
                {
                    //matrix[row][col] = new_img.getRGB(row, col);
                    new_img.getRaster().getDataElements(row, col, pix);
                    matrix[row][col] = pix[0];
                }
                    for(int J = 0; J < firstRow; J++) 
                    {   
                        //if (row != J){
                            // set a pixel
                            //int image = image1.getRGB( row, col, pixelValue );
                            //image.setRGB(x, y, pixelValue);

                        if (row == J){
                            System.out.println("x,y: " + row + ", " + J + "num of Detectors: " + numOfDetectors);
                            new_img.setRGB = ((row + numOfDetectors) + (row - 1)/ 2);

                            if (row == J && numOfDetectors > 20){
                                System.out.println("x,y: " + row + ", " + J + "num of Detectors: " + numOfDetectors + "then > 20");
                                //new_img.setRGB(x, y, pixelValue);
                                int col = new_img.getHeight();
                                new_img.getRaster().getDataElements(row, col, pix);
                                matrix[row][col] = pix[0];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    try {
                        //ImageIO.write(new_img, format, file);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally { System.out.println("Images were written succesfully.");}  
                    System.out.println("rest of the code...");
                    }
            }  finally {
        }     
    }
```

}

Comment: `setRGB` is a method, not a field.  You can call it, but you can't assign to it.  (Since you're new to Java, some useful advice:  Never ever catch `Exception`.  Catch only what you need to catch.)

Comment: "_I'm having problems with setRGB in[...] and IOException e, in [...]"_ -- Please, share the stacktrace and the exception message if you want some useful feedback.

Comment: is here .. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 setRGB cannot be resolved or is not a field
 IOException cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: So .. for set pixel ? how to do ?